# transform matrix and repeat values

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have this matrix:

```
a1 a2 a3 a4 a5
b1 b2 b3 b4 b5
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
d1 d2 d3 d4 d5
e1 e2 e3 e4 e5
```

and i need to transform it to this matrix:

```
a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 c1 c2 c3
a2 a3 a4 b2 b3 b4 c2 c3 c4
a3 a4 a5 b3 b4 b5 c3 c4 c5
b1 b2 b3 c1 c2 c3 d1 d2 d3
b2 b3 b4 c2 c3 c4 d2 d3 d4
b3 b4 b5 c3 c4 c5 d3 d4 d5
c1 c2 c3 d1 d2 d3 e1 e2 e3
c2 c3 c4 d2 d3 d4 e2 e3 e4
c3 c4 c5 d3 d4 d5 e3 e4 e5
```

i.e. by taking a 3x3 matrix and iterating over the old matrix putting it as a new row in the new matrix.
How can i do this in matlab? I heard loops are very bad and if I can I should use matrix operations.

Comment: Really what you are looking for is what operations you could perform to transform matrix A into matrix B. This is not a programming question, but a math question. As far as I am concerned, I don't know why you try to use anything BUT a loop to do this, especially since you're dealing with a 9x9 matrix

Comment: because i'm using matlab and need this transformation here... so its more a programming question then math i think

Comment: Loops are not very bad.  I expect that by the time someone here on SO guides you to a working answer without loops you will have wasted about 1 zillion times more time waiting than any possible time saved by using a non-loop-based solution.

Comment: I don't understand why people are voting to close this for being off-topic or difficult to understand.  And I invite those, like @bengoesboom, who think that this is maths- rather than programming-related to post a mathematical solution.  It may not be a very good question but it seems entirely programming-related to me.

Comment: mhh... my question was answered, but still it was closed. thats nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to image processing toolbox you can use [`im2col`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) which even works for **symbolic variables** too.

```
A = sym('A%d%d', [5 5]);
A = sym(A, 'real');

Subs = mat2cell(im2col(A, [3 1])', 3*ones(1,5));
Res = im2col(Subs, [3 1]);
```

`Res` is a cell matrix containing the sub matrices.

To **concatenate** it into a matrix:

```
reshape([Res{:}]', [9 9])
```

or if it's not symbolic this also works: `cell2mat(Res)`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code :

```
clear
clc

a1 = 1; a2 = 2; a3 = 3; a4 = 4; a5 = 5;
b1 = 11; b2 = 12; b3 = 13; b4 = 14; b5 = 15;
c1 = 21; c2 = 22; c3 = 23; c4 = 24; c5 = 25;
d1 = 31; d2 = 32; d3 = 33; d4 = 34; d5 = 35;
e1 = 41; e2 = 42; e3 = 43; e4 = 44; e5 = 45;

A = [a1 a2 a3 a4 a5; b1 b2 b3 b4 b5; c1 c2 c3 c4 c5; d1 d2 d3 d4 d5; e1 e2 e3 e4 e5];
B = zeros(9,9);

sizeA = size(A);
sizeB = size(B);

jj = 1;
kk = 1;

for ii = 1 : sizeB(1)    
    B(ii,1:sizeB(1)) = [A(kk, jj:jj+2) A(kk + 1, jj:jj+2) A(kk + 2, jj:jj+2)]
    jj = jj + 1;
    if mod(ii,3) == 0
        kk = kk + 1;
        jj = 1;
    end
end
```

I tested it for your case where A is 5x5 and B is 9x9. Might need to be modified to work with different size of A and B.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a somewhat general sense, but it is not pretty:

```
a = [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5];
b = [b1, b2, b3, b4, b5];
% etc.

% Rearrange your vector into a matrix configured how you want it
A = flipdim(toeplitz(a),1); % 5 x 5 matrix in our case
A = A(ceil(size(A,1)/2):size(A,1), ceil(size(A,2)/2):size(A,2)); % now 3 x 3

%%%
% Repeat similar process for b --> B, c --> C, etc.
%%%

% Build the resulting matrix up block-by-block
M = [A, B, C;
     B, C, D;
     C, D, E];
```

I was unable to find a good way to generalize the construction of `M`, and unfortunately forming a toeplitz matrix using `toeplitz([a,b,c,d,e])` fails; you do not get the right format for your sub-matrices. Still, you may be able to use this to start on something.